# Error 1049 unknown database on attempting to connect to MySQL via MySQL Monitor

Tags: mysql, sql

Initially  I tried dumping a database using mysqldump, which resulted in [error] unknown variable 'database=<db_I_deleted>', where db_I_deleted is not the database I was trying to backup. The database in the error was one that I had created in doing something else at a different time and had no need for any longer. So I connected to mysql as user and dropped the database. This did not change the aforementioned error when running mysqldump again. Now when I try to connect to mysql in the shell I receive ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '<db_I_deleted>'. The same message is displayed when connecting as root. What can I do to at least restore access to mysql without nuking it?

It may be worth noting that all database users are validated via auth_socket.

Update: by supplying a specific database as argument I can access mysql monitor. From monitor confirmed empty querycache with SHOW STATUS LIKE '%Qcache%'; listing an empty set.

Comment: It's probably related to the tool your are using to connect to the database. It probably cached the last database you used.

Comment: I am using mysql as a command in the shell to connect. Is that Incorrect terminology? I am using version 8 so if you mean to say cached queries I think that has been removed.

Comment: try to connect to mysql without giving a database
mysql -usuername -ppassword -haddress

Comment: The opposite actually worked, by specifying a database I can get into mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I had followed a tutorial a long time ago that configured a client in /etc/mysql/my.cnf that used the database that I had removed. Removing the mention of the client resolved both access problem and the problem with mysqldump.